# Rails I18n accepts_nested_attributes_for and error_messages_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, error-messages-for

I've got two models

```
class SurveyResponse
  has_many :answers, :class_name => SurveyResponseAnswer.name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class SurveyResponseAnswer
  belongs_to :survey_response
  validates_presence_of :answer_text
end
```

In my nested form if validation fails I get this error displayed on the screen:

"answers answer text can't be blank"

I've customized my attribute names somewhat successfully using rails I18n.  It doesn't behave exactly how I would expect though.  The yml file below doesn't affect how the attribute name is printed in error_messages_for

```
en: 
  activerecord:
    models:
      survey_response:
        answers: "Response"
```

But if from script/console I try
    SurveyResponse.human_attribute_name("answers")

I get the expected result of "Response".

What I'd like to do is have the validation error message say:

"Response answer text can't be blank".  Any ideas what I need to fix?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
en: 
  activerecord:
    models:
      survey_response:
        answers:
          answer_text: "Response"
```

I am using Rails 3 and this is working for me (my i18n file is a bit different, using "attributes" instead of models. I don't know if this works in 2.3)

```
en: 
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      survey_response:
        answers:
          answer_text: "Response"
```

Before that I was trying to create a attribute in the yml called "answers_answer_text" but it was not working.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Actually, not so fine: ´[DEPRECATION WARNING] Nested I18n namespace lookup under "activerecord.attributes.survey_response" is no longer supported´. But going by [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1869), there doesn't seem to be a fully working non-deprecated alternative yet.

Answer (score 62):

As of Rails 3.2.0, the i18n yaml has changed to

```
en: 
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      survey_response:
        foo: "Foo"
      survey_response/answers:
        answer_text: "Response"
```

(Note the slash.) This also permits you to define an attribute name on the collection itself, e.g.

```
en: 
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      survey_response:
        foo: "Foo"
        answers: "Ripostes"
      survey_response/answers:
        answer_text: "Response"
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3859

Comment: Thankyou very much. I can confirm that this works for me in Rails 3.2.8 where nothing else did. Took me over an hour of searching!

Comment: This is exactly what i want. :)

Comment: I'm just trying to define an attribute name for the collection (eg. `survey_response.answers: Ripostes`) and can't get it to work on Rails 5.0.1. Specifying the specific field works like you mentioned (`survey_response/answers.answer_text`), but I can't get it to recognize the collection fallback.

Comment: @stephen.hanson did you ever figure that one out? same issue here, trying to define the model name for an error message on a nested_attributes form