# Validate nested attributes error messages en.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, yaml

I am customising my validation error messages and am having no problem validating my recipe model, but I cannot validate my nested model ingredients.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :preperations

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
```

This is my YAML file:

```
    en:
      errors:
        format: "%{message}"

         activerecord:
           errors:
             models: 
               recipe: 
                attributes:
                 dish_name:
                  blank: "Dont forget to give your Recipe a Dish Name"
                 country:
                  blank: "Dont forget to add the country name"
                 category:
                  blank: "Dont forget the category"
                 difficulty:
                  blank: "Dont forget to add the difficulty"
                 preperation_time:
                  blank: "Dont forget the preperation time"
              recipe/ingredients:
                attributes:
                 ingredient_name:
                 blank: "Cant have a recipe without ingredients can we?"
```

How do i set the validation for nested models?

any help appreciated, thanks.

Edit

I am using rails 3.2.3 and for some reason the : on the end of recipes/ingredients is white not purple like the rest of my :

Comment: I expect you intended the last `class Recipe` to be `class Ingredient`? Also, the YML indentation seems off.

Comment: What do you mean by nested in this case? Looks like you just have two models `Recipe` and `Ingredient`. If so, just validate each as you would separately.

Comment: See this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058968/rails-i18n-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-error-messages-for

Comment: im looking at that now, just found it, doesnt seem to work? maybe my formatting is incorrect?

Comment: If you're on Rails 3.2, make sure to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11129637/6962 and not just the top answer.

Comment: still not working, struggling with the indentation it seems and i have added edit to post, appreciate any help you can offer

Comment: Yes, your indentation looks weird. Run it against a [YAML validator](http://yamllint.com/) and make sure it's valid. Sibling nodes must be preceded by the same amount of spaces. Two extra spaces for each level is common but not required. Your last "blank" should be under "ingredient_name" but isn't now.