# Rails translate validation error messages for nested attributes i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, localization, nested-attributes

The error message doesn't translate my nested model attributes, since it is defined as singular but in the error messages it looks for a plural.

I've got a Model 'Person' which has_many :addresses. This Person model accepts nested attributes of 'Addresses'.
I am creating Addresses only along with a Person model.

my locale file looks like

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      person:
        one: "Person"
        other: "People"
      address:
        one: 'Address'
        other: 'Addresses'
    attributes:
      person:
        first_name: 'First name'
        last_name: 'Last name'
        middle_name: 'Middel name'
      address:
        street: street
        city: city
        country: country
```

and for the error message:

```
en:
  errors: &errors
    format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
    messages:
      blank: can't be blank
```

It works with single Models but with nested attributes i've got a problem with the validation messages.

Since the message is displayed like:

```
 @messages=
  {:first_name=>["can't be blank"],
   :last_name=>["can't be blank"],
   :"addresses.street"=>["can't be blank"],
   :"addresses.city"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

the lookup doesn't find the translation for addresses.street, since it is just address.street in the yml file.

How can i make it find address.street when it looks for addresses.street without doubleing all my entries?

Comment: Maybe [this so answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11129637/660260) might help.

Answer (score -1):

did you look up how to handle pluralization in the Rails Doc

[rails i18n][1]  [1]: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization

3 Pluralization
In English there are only one singular and one plural form for a given string, e.g. "1 message" and "2 messages". Other languages (Arabic, Japanese, Russian and many more) have different grammars that have additional or fewer plural forms. Thus, the I18n API provides a flexible pluralization feature.