# Rails 4 Accepts Nested Attributes Internationalisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, yaml

According to most of Google and SO, the solution to the problem of internationalising in Rails, in particular nested attributes, is to use this syntax, with a forward slash:

```
en: 
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      box/forwards:
        source: "Origin"
```

From the following:

[Rails I18n accepts_nested_attributes_for and error_messages_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058968/rails-i18n-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-error-messages-for)

And this pull request in Rails (ages ago):

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3859

This does not work for me. Assuming, I have the following arrangement in a 'box' model:

```
has_many :forwards
accepts_nested_attributes_for :forwards, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

So far, I've tried:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:

      forward:
        source: "ABC"

      forwards:
        source: "CDF"

      box:
        forward:
          source: "SDS"

      box:
        forwards:
          source: "SDS"

      box/forward:
        source: "BBB"

      box/forwards:
        source: "BBB"
```

In Rails 4.1.6, how on earth can one alter the nested field names in en.yml?